# Appendices in article

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, appendices

What I'm trying to do is make the title **Appendices** appear. My current code is more or less like this:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,bottom=1in,top=1in,left=0.9in,right=0.9in]{geometry}
\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents
%SECTIONS
\input{intro/intro.tex}
\input{KGDirac/KGDirac.tex}
\input{HField/HField.tex}
\input{HiggMech/HiggMech.tex}
\input{massSM/massMS.tex}
\input{discov/discov.tex}
\input{Autoacop/Autoacop.tex}
\input{conc/conc.tex}
%REFERENCES
\printbibliography[title={Bibliografía},heading=bibintoc]
%APPENDICES
\appendix
\input{apendix/dlips.tex}
```

and this is what I get in the table of contents:

[image: Table of contents]

and at the beginning of the appendices:

[image: Beginning of Appendices]

What I want is that the title Appendices appear after Bibliography in Table of Contents and before the first section of the appendices. Do you know how?

Answer (score 1):

You can have it  with

```
\usepackage{appendix}
   ...................
\begin{document}
   ...................
\begin{appendices}[toc,titletoc]
   ...................
\end{appendices}
```

Comment: Is there any other option? When I use that one many errors appears

Comment: You can do part of the job with `titlesec`, but that is strange.  Can you compile just the code you posted (not the full document) with the addition I suggest?