# Add an Appendix in an APA6 class article environment, listed in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, apa-style

I would like to add an Appendix into my Apa6 class article that appears also in the ToC. Moreover, if possible, could I add a separate LoF/LoT for the Appendix. I will add the packages I am using.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,natbib,donotrepeattitle]{apa6}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{minipage-marginpar}
%Table, Caption, Title positioning [H]
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
\restylefloat{figure}
```

Comment: For the first question, you can try my answer to [appendices in article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/431466/appendices-in-article/431471#431471).

Comment: Thank you, sadly that does not work.

Comment: Could you post a full, yet minimal compilable code which reproduces the problem?